# DCP analysis rules for the constraints in CVXPY

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

Why is `cvxpy.square(x) >= 0` in the constraints not DCP (disciplined convex programming; *explicit* rules can be found [here](https://dcp.stanford.edu/rules)), whereas the expression `cvxpy.square(x)` as an objective is DCP?

A more general question would be: what role does `>=` play in the automatic curvature analysis? / what does the "curvature" of an inequality/equality expression mean?

Comment: You should add "as an objective in a minimization problem", because you could not maximize it, which is the same reason you cannot use it on the left of > (minimizing f(x) is the same as writing t>=f(x), maximizing f(x) is the same as writing f(x)>=t). On the left hand side of > you must have a concave expression, on the right a convex expression.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks. But isn't "minimizing x^2 subject to x^2 >= 0" the same as just "minimizing x^2" because the constraint is already met for any real x? In any case, I'd like to know the *DCP rules* for constraints, which is more about the implementation than the math, I guess.

Comment: You know the constraint is met, but how can CVXPY know that? You could maybe expect cvxpy to know that x^2 is nonnegative (actually maybe it does) but then it would effectively have to skip this constraint (since the solver won't accept it) which would be even more confusing.  DCP rules for constraints are in https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/#dcp-problems

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you! That's tremendously helpful.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  It is a mathematical question.